# Is there any application about aws-iot device shadow?

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, aws-iot

I have read the document of aws-iot, and successfully run the sample code.
I would like to know some applications using device shadow.  Real-world application is better.

Comment: suppose you have a building with multiple devices controlling the lights and one of them loses connection from time to time.  and you use some queues to deliver commands to such devices. You are switching on the light in the evening and switching it off in the morning. Suppose failing device restores connection and gets multiple commands to switch the light on and off , lets suppose about 100 of such commands. Light will start blinking. And there could be commands to close and open windows (shutters control). And so on. When shadow is used device will get single command to change its state.

Comment: Demo with many device shadows: https://gambitcomm.blogspot.com/2019/05/mimic-mqtt-simulator-dynamic-scalable.html